# Creating object events - canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i am learning Canvas. I dont know why i cant create an object Events. In my console i have communication error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Events is not defined(...)". Can u help me repair it?

Here is code
events.js:

```
function addPoint(events, points){
    var context = events.getContext();
    var drawingPos = events.getMousePos();

    if(drawingPos !== null){
        points.push(drawingPos);
    }
}

function drawPath(canvas, points, canvasImg){
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    context.drawImage(canvasImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
    context.beginPatch();
    context.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    for(var n = 1; n < points.length; n++){
        var point = points[n];
        context,lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    }
    context.stroke();
}

function updateColorSquare(){
    var red = document.getElementById("Red").value;
    var green = document.getElementById("Green").value;
    var blue = document.getElementById("Blue").value; 
    var colorSquare = document.getElementById("colorSquare");
    colorSquare.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
}

function getCanvasImg(canvas){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    return img;
}

window.onload = function(){
    var events = new Events("myCanvas"); <----- HERE IS PROBLEM.
    var canvas = events.getCanvas();
    var context = events.getContext();
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var canvasImg = getCanvasImg(canvas);
    var points = [];

    //inicjalizacja parametrów rysowania
    var red = document.getElementById("red").value;
    var green = document.getElementById("green").value;
    var blue = document.getElementById("blue").value;
    var size = document.getElementById("size").value;

    document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("keyup", function(evt){
        updateColorSquare();
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("green").addEventListener("keyup", function(evt){
        updateColorSquare();
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("blue").addEventListener("keyup", function(evt){
        updateColorSquare();
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("clearButton").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
        events.clear();
        points =[];
        canvasImg = getCanvasImg(canvas);
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("saveButton").addEventListener("click", function(evt){

        window.open(canvas.toDataURL());
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        var drawingPos = events.getMousePos();

        red = document.getElementById("red").value;
        green = document.getElementById("green").value;
        blue = document.getElementById("blue").value;
        size = document.getElementById("size").value;

        context.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
        context.lineWidth = size;
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.lineCap = "round";
        addPoint(events, points);
        isMouseDown = true;
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
        isMouseDown = false;
        if(points.length > 0) {
            drawPath(this, points, canvasImg);
            //wyczyszczenie punktów
            points = [];
        }
        canvas = getCanvasImg(this);
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        if(document.createEvent){
            var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initEvent("mouseup", true, false);
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        else {
            this.fireEvent("onmouseup");
        }
    }, false);

    events.setDrawStage(function(){
        if(isMouseDown){
            addPoint(this,points);
            drawPath(canvas, points, canvasImg);
        }
    });
};
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here2</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link2</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <div class="container">TEST</div>
    <div id="toolbar">
    <label>
    Kolor:
    </label>
    R: <input type="text" id="red" maxlength="3" class="short" value="0">
    G: <input type="text" id="green" maxlength="3" class="short" value="0">
    B: <input type="text" id="blue" maxlength="3" class="short" value="255">
    <div id="colorSquare">
    </div>
    <label>
        Wielkość:
    </label>

    <input type="text" id="size" maxlength="3" class="short" value="20">px
    <input type="button" id="clearButton"value="Wyczyść">
    <input type="button" id="saveButton"value="Zapisz">
    </div>
    <canvs id="myCanvas" width="600" heigth="250">
    </canvs>
     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/events.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Isn't `Events` supposed to be `Event`? In other words: Typo?

Comment: This may not be related to the error, but you wrote `canvs` instead of `canvas` in your html.

Comment: When i change Events to Event (var events = new Event("myCanvas");) i have second error: Uncaught TypeError: events.getCanvas is not a function...